# Twilio - can't add emergency address, can't release number

Tags: twilio, release

I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place with my Twilio number. Thanks to the new A2P 10DLC requirements, my home IoT SMS needs have moved to Telegram. However, I need to release my phone number. If I attempt to release the phone number, it tells me I need to remove the emergency call address. If I go to "Configure", it asks me to add an emergency address. What? How can I remove an address I don't have? It rejects almost any address add attempt and tells me to try again later. So, I can't add an emergency address, I can't remove one, and I can't release the number. Clearly something is bungled up on Twilio's side, but it appears that the world will moss over before they take the time to respond. Has anyone else encountered this? Any easy solutions other than Twilio needing to intervene? Thanks in advance!

1. Tried to add emergency address. Tells me to try again later. 2. Tried to release number. Tells me to remove emergency address. 3. ??? 4. Profit?

Comment: Are you tying to "release" a number or "port away" a number? Release is described here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183028-Cancel-or-release-a-Twilio-number Porting is described here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179588-How-do-I-port-my-phone-numbers-away-from-Twilio-

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Trying to release, but something was broken on the back end. Twilio ended up having to manually do something to remove an address in an invalid state and I was then able to remove it. Frustrating though, because there was literally no way to do it without their intervention on this.

Comment: Have the same problem. I am trying to release, delete or otherwise completely get rid of a number. There is no way to remove the emergency address, the button referred to in the documentation "Remove this Address" simply does not exist, and the number cannot be released with an emergency address attached. This is 100% clearly and obviously a bug on Twilio's part.